# Postgresql: ERROR: syntax error at or near "integer"

Tags: postgresql

I am getting this error while declaring variables in this postgres query , really not sure what the issue is,I am new to postgres. thank for feedback

```
DECLARE
maxpagecount integer;
rowsofpage integer;  
pagenumber integer; 
Set rowsofpage :=3;
Set pagenumber :=1;
select maxpagecount=count(*) from UNLABELED_IMAGE_PREDICTION;
Set maxpagecount = CEILING(Maxpagecount/rowsofpage);
While maxpagecount >= pagenumber
BEGIN
        Select x.image_id,x.score
         from (
            select *,row_number() over (order by score desc) as row_count
             from UNLABELED_IMAGE_PREDICTION
            ) x
        where x.row_count <= (select count(*) from UNLABELED_IMAGE_PREDICTION)
        
      OFFSET (pagenumber-1)* rowsofpage ROWS
      FETCH first rowsofpage ROWS ONLY;
      Set rowsOfpage =rowsOfpage + 1
      Set pagenumber=pagenumber+1

END;
```

Comment: you need PL/pgSQL to be able to define variables in a function, procedure or [do block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). And [assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) is not done using `SET`

Comment: This structure is not valid, a lot stuff is missing or just wrong. Did you start with the manual when you started writing code? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-programming.html